# Reflecting Enum Values in an external Assembly

Tags: .net, reflection, enums

My aim is to enumerate DLLs in a folder, look for classes that conform to a specific interface and then query those classes for enum values.  The idea being that I want to query what 'Outcome' possibilities are supported.

I have my DLLs lined up and can see the classes which conform to the correct interface, that is working, but the next step is to search the class for a specific enum and get the values, I have been using the following code:

```
Private Sub GetOutcomeEnumValues(ByVal AssemblyPath As String, ByVal ClassName As String)
        Dim ReflectedAssembly As Assembly
        Dim ReflectedClass As Type
        'Load DLL
        ReflectedAssembly = System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFrom(AssemblyPath)
        'Load Class
        ReflectedClass = ReflectedAssembly.GetType(ClassName)
        'Load members
        Dim Members() As MemberInfo
        Members = ReflectedClass.GetMembers
        For i As Integer = 0 To Members.Count - 1
            'Check for the Outcomes enumeration
            If (Members(i).Name = "Outcomes") Then
                Dim Outcomes As System.Array
                Outcomes = Members(i).GetType.GetEnumValues
            End If
        Next
    End Sub
```

The problem I have is that I cannot seem to get Members(i) to give me the enum values - even though I KNOW this Member is an enumeration.  When I call 'GetEnumValues' an exception is thrown:

"Type provided must be an Enum.  Parameter name: enumType"

The class I am querying looks something like this

```
Public Class Foo
    Public Enum Outcomes
        OK
        Cancel
    End Enum
End Class
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it, after experimenting a little, I used the following code to good effect:

```
Private Sub GetOutcomeEnumValues(ByVal AssemblyPath As String, ByVal ClassName As String)
    Dim ReflectedAssembly As Assembly
    Dim ReflectedClass As Type
    'Load DLL
    ReflectedAssembly = System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFrom(AssemblyPath)
    'Load Class
    ReflectedClass = ReflectedAssembly.GetType(ClassName & "+ Outcomes")
    'Load members
    Dim OutcomeNames() As String = ReflectedClass.GetEnumNames

End Sub
```